# is there any way to output the html from google chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a website that uses javascript to change the HTML dynamically based on input. I use google developer tools to examine the HTML at any particular moment in the lifetime of the page. Is there any way easy way to output the HTML from the elements tab to a file or to the clipboard (so that I can run it thru a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) for debugging)? Control + A does not allow me to select all of the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Copy the `<html>` element as HTML:

[image]

... but you can do this easier at the console:

`copy(document.documentElement.outerHTML);`

Note that neither of these will copy the doctype.  Also this is the serialization of the live DOM which could be totally different than the markup you served. But you know that.